# Java não compila .java

Tags: java, java-8

Java não compila retorno erro não é possível localizar nem carregar classe principal com.sun.tools.javac.Main.

Comment: Sempre coloque informações com mais detalhes,por exemplo no seu caso,coloque o log do erro que ocorreu.

Answer (score 1):

Você provavelmente fez a instalação do JDK manualmente,e por isto está dando este erro,pois deve ter dado algum erro na instalação do Java.

Execute o seguinte comando,no seu `JAVA_HOME/lib directory` :

> unpack200 -r -v -l "" tools.pack tools.jar

Isto irá desempacotar o tools.jar arquivo que é o que provavelmente está causando o erro.

Depois disto,tente o seguinte comando :

> javac -version

Caso quiser dar uma olhada melhor sobre o assunto,olhe [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808829/jre-1-7-returns-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-lang-object?answertab=votes#tab-top) sobre mais detalhes.